# Facebook meta tags not working properly on WordPress Site

Tags: plugins, facebook, open-graph

I want tow things in my site. First when any user click on `facebook` button to `share` any post it shwo `image` and `content`, `title` only and the 2nd one is when any one copy the link of my site and directly paste it into `facebook` then it show. site `name`,`logo` and `description`. Now the main problem is i have two option one is i use `meta tag` of `facebook` in header or i can use any plugin in for this. Now i am using `plugin` in [Wondermoon's](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wonderm00ns-simple-facebook-open-graph-tags/). Now the problem is some post creating little problem. i attach images [image][image][image][image]

Now these are 4 images. First three images are when user click on `share` button. And it show different content. The correct one is 3rd. Don't know what is problem with 1st two.
And the last image is when any one paste the link of site on facebook. It not show any `logo` or `site` `name`,`description`. So is there any solution for this. Or any `plugin` in. Thanks

Comment: If you have issue with how plugin had tried contacting plugin's developer? Can you provide URL to site?

Comment: www.tripgoggles.com this is the site link